# Elegir el menor numero positivo de una fila sobre una matriz

Tags: c#

Estoy realizando un ejercicio donde debo especificar cual es el numero con menor valor sobre una fila en una matriz.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi código hace la detección del numero con menor valor con normalidad, pero, cuando una fila esta llena de números positivos, me imprime un 0 y no imprime el numero menor positivo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar en las 2 ultimas imágenes, la ultima fila de la matriz esta llena de positivos y me dice que el numero menor es un 0.
Este es mi código:

```
    public void metodo(int[,] arr, int cc, int ff)
    {
        for (int f = 0; f < cc; f++)
        {
            
            float menorfila = 0;    
            for (int c = 0; c < ff; c++)
            {
                
                if (arr[f, c] < menorfila)
                {
                    menorfila = arr[f, c];
                }
            }
            
            Console.WriteLine("EL ELEMENTO MENOR DE LA FILA ES: " + f + " = " + menorfila);
        }
    }
```

de pronto la variable que uso como "menorfila = 0" pueda ser el problema, pero no logro entender como solucionar este inconveniente.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes poner como valor inicial de comparación el primero en vez de cero (`arr[f, 0]`)

```
public void metodo(int[,] arr, int cc, int ff)
{
    for (int f = 0; f < cc; f++)
    {
        
        float menorfila = arr[f, 0];    
        for (int c = 0; c < ff; c++)
        {
            
            if (arr[f, c] < menorfila)
            {
                menorfila = arr[f, c];
            }
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine("EL ELEMENTO MENOR DE LA FILA ES: " + f + " = " + menorfila);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es por esa variable menorfila la inicializas en 0 Y la compara con los demás
Lo que podrias hacer es inicial con el Primer valor de cada fila:

```
public void metodo(int[,] arr, int cc, int ff)
{
    for (int f = 0; f < cc; f++)
    {
        
        float menorfila = 0;    
        for (int c = 0; c < ff; c++)
        {
            
            if (arr[f, c] < menorfila)
            {
                menorfila = arr[f, c];
            }
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine("EL ELEMENTO MENOR DE LA FILA ES: " + f + " = " + menorfila);
    }
}
```